# Find-Item and the _Source field

Tags: powershell-extensions

Trying use `Find-Item` to get all items where `_Source` has a value set. Normally the `_Source` is null, so I thought that this would be sufficient - check for `$null` with `-Invert` set:

```
$FilterCriteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_Source"; Value = $null; Invert=$true },
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/Website/sitex" }
)

$itemsToProcess = Find-Item -Index "sitecore_master_index" -Criteria $FilterCriteria -First 10 | Initialize-Item
```

It isn't working... Then I thought that I could use "contains" as filter for `_Source-field`, as the field starts with a "sitecore..."-string if set:

```
$FilterCriteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Contains"; Field = "_Source"; Value = "sitecore" },
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/Website/sitex" }
)

$itemsToProcess = Find-Item -Index "sitecore_master_index" -Criteria $FilterCriteria -First 10 | Initialize-Item
```

Nothing seems to be working on the "_Source"-field - any clues to make this work?!?

Comment: What field type is _Source?

Comment: The field type is “Version Link”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Solr won't store anything for null value so you can try wildcard character "*".

I have tested below example and its working.

You need to make sure that _source field exists in Solr. Also, since all fields in Solr are in lowercase so you need to change the case from `_Source` to `_source`.

```
$FilterCriteria = @(
    @{Filter = "Equals"; Field = "_source"; Value = "*"; },
    @{Filter = "StartsWith"; Field = "_fullpath"; Value = "/sitecore/content/Website/sitex" }
)

$itemsToProcess = Find-Item -Index "sitecore_master_index" -Criteria $FilterCriteria -First 10 | Initialize-Item
```

Comment: @KurtBilde - did it work for you?

Comment: Nope but this it must be due to the field missing in the index....